# How to render new page in react router v6 without adding other components?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a Login Button inside the Landing Page When I click the login button the component renders inside the Landing Page. What I want to do is render a new page how do I do that with react-router v6?

I'm Creating a Shop App
This is my App.js

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Intro from "./components/Intro";
import Shelf from "./components/Shelf";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Intro />
      <Shelf />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the intro Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup'

function Intro() {

return (
    <div className="hero">
        <div className="overlay column ai-center js-center">
            <h1 className="m-0 fs-large"><em>Welcome to Furns</em></h1>
            <hr />
            <p className="m-0 fs-small">Worlwide known company serves the best furnitures</p>
            <div className="row mt-4">
                <Router>

                   
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
                        </Routes>
                    
                    <Link to="/login">
                        <button className="login-btn-large px mx-3">Login</button>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/signup" >
                        <button className="sign-up-btn">Sign-up</button>
                    </Link>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


);
}

export default Intro;
```

And Here's my Login component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Login() {

return (
  
        <div className="float shadow bg-light px-3 py-3 ai-center js-between">
            <h2 className="brand color-olive">Furns</h2>
            <h1 className="color-olive">Login</h1>
            <form className="column">
                <label htmlFor="username" className="color-olive my-1"> Username</label>
                <input id="username" type="text" className="txt-box" />

                <label htmlFor="password" className="color-olive my-1">Password </label>
                <input id="password" type="password" className="txt-box" />


                <button type="submit" className="mt-4 olive login-btn-large">Login</button>
                <button className="my-1 olive bg-light btn-cancel" >Cancel</button>

            </form>

        </div>
    
);
}

    export default Login;
```

This is how it looks like when I clicked the log in button

[Login Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDR9Z.jpg)

Comment: Need to see what you are trying first. Please add some of the code you have done.

Comment: SO *isn't* a code writing or tutorial service. Have you already tried something on your own? Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are wanting or trying to do?

Comment: I edited the post that's how the code looks like....and I already tried searching but tutorials are all the same most of it is about the v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question and code correctly, `Intro` is what you are calling your landing page, and you want it to link to the other pages.

For this I suggest this refactor:

1. Render the `Router` and routes in `App` where `Intro` is currently being rendered.
2. Create a new route specifically for the landing intro page.

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Intro />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
        <Shelf />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Intro

```
function Intro() {
  return (
    <div className="hero">
      <div className="overlay column ai-center js-center">
        <h1 className="m-0 fs-large"><em>Welcome to Furns</em></h1>
        <hr />
        <p className="m-0 fs-small">Worlwide known company serves the best furnitures</p>
        <div className="row mt-4">
          <Link to="/login">
            <button className="login-btn-large px mx-3">Login</button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/signup" >
            <button className="sign-up-btn">Sign-up</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you don't want, or need, the `Header` and/or `Shelf` components to render on all pages then you can abstract these into a layout wrapper component that then renders an `Outlet` for wrapped routes to render into.

```
const PageLayout = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    <Shelf />
  </div>
);
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Intro />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<PageLayout />} >
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: @weak-coder Have you had a chance to try this solution out?